# Resizing first column gives _this.widthGetters[columnName] is not a function ( devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress

Resizing the first column in **Grid** of **dx-react-grid-material-ui** is resulting in a empty screen with following error

> _this.widthGetters[columnName] is not a function when resizing

[ERROR SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwpHW.png)

i suspect table column resizing

```
<TableColumnResizing defaultColumnWidths={columnWidths} />
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that this problem is solved in the 3.0.2 version. Upgrading @devexpress also requires upgrading react to v17.0.2+ and MUI to v5+. All changelog there:
https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Currently already 3.0.3 version. still same error.

for mine case, i need to use align and auto resize features. so mine component will have 
<Table columnExtensions={vState.tableColumnExtensions} /> 
& 
<TableColumnResizing
            defaultColumnWidths={vState.defaultColumnWidths}
            resizingMode={"nextColumn"} />